# How do I configure ModelMapper to map only the exact matching fields in both source and destination?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I tried `MatchingStrategy` as `STRICT` but that won't update anything since I do not have same number properties in both source and destination.

`STANDARD` is not working because there's this one property called `id` in source and `personId` in destination. so `id` is being mapped to `personId` which I do not want. If I skip this property then I am getting an error that `A mapping is missing a required destination member`.